# Python Indexing not returning expected value

Tags: python

I am trying to return the value M from Mr. Smith but whenever I run my code below it returns ''

```
>>>name = input("Please input your name: ")
Please input your name: Mr. Smith 
>>> if name == name.find(' ') and name.isalpha():
    get_initial = name[0]
>>>get_initial
''
```

Comment: `str.find` returns the index of character(s) in the string. Do you know that?

Comment: I do now that but the name could vary so I want to know how to find the first index value of any given name input

Comment: You probably want to `strip` your string input. This removes whitespace from both ends. `name = name.strip(); name[0]`. Unless you want to keep the whitespace

Comment: Please, start with a tutorial…

Answer (score 2):

python 3

```
   name = input("Please input your name: ")
    c=name.strip()[0]
    if c.isalpha():
        print(c)
```

python 2 :

```
>>> name = raw_input("Please input your name: ")
Please input your name:   Hisham
>>> c=name.strip()[0]
>>> if c.isalpha():
    print c
```

output py3:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

Please input your name:   dsfgsdf
d
```

output py2:

```
H
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of problems in this proposed code.

First of all, `input()` evaluates the input string as a python expression and that's not what you want, you need to use `raw_input()` instead.
Second, `isalpha()` won't return True if input includes '.' or spaces, so you need to find another metric, for example, if only alphabetical characters are allowed, you can use `isalpha()` this way:

```
name_nospaces = "".join(name.split())
if name_nospaces.isalpha():
    ...
```

Then, it doesn't make much sense to do `name == name.find(' ')`, just have:

```
if name.find(' '):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have to find the first character of a name....

```
def find_initial(name):
    i = 0
    initial_name_size = len(name)

    while True:
        name = name[i:]
        if name.isalpha():
            get_initial = name[0]
            return get_initial
        else:
            i = i+1
            if i >= initial_name_size:
                return 'There is no initial'


name = input("Please input your name: ")
print find_initial(name)
```

Comment: input: Madam. Tusade
output: T